# Restrict language content for a given role

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site (spanish/english). I created 1 role: **translator**.

I need the **anonymous users** to ONLY see the contents in english language and the **translator users** to see both.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I bet there can be a better solution than: Having a language switch block only visible for users with the role translator and as a second step hooking into node_load procedure and denying access(or redirect to english page) for anonymous users when they try to see a page in spanish. AsI said I believe there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve it can be this.  Note I am assuming you are using the standard node-based translations, and *not* entity-based translations.

Suppose the content is a node-type one and the content-type is called `Page_en_es`.  Give permissions at `/admin/people/permissions`:

1. `View own unpublished content`, `Page_en_es: Edit any content` etc to *translator users*
2. `View published content` to *anonymous users*.

Then, whenever a translator edits or creates the Spanish content, s/he will set it (=node) to be **not** published.  And the Spanish version won't be seen by anonymous users.